# Why is TcpClient.Connect() throwing System.AggregateException

Tags: exception, tcp, tcpclient, aggregateexception

I am trying to check the TCP connection to a localhost TCP server using following code:

```
string host = "localhost";
int port = 61616;
using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient())
{
    try
    {


        Task t = Task.Run(() => {
            tcpClient.Connect(host, port);
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Connected.");
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150);
        if (!t.Wait(ts))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The timeout interval elapsed.");
            Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to: {0}", port);// ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Port.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Port {0} open.", port);
        }
     }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught unauthorized access exception-await behavior");
    }
    catch (AggregateException )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Caught aggregate exception-Task.Wait behavior");
    }
```

I stopped the localhost server, and tried to run the above code. It threw `System.AggregateException`. When I started the server and ran the code; it connects to the server.

According to the [documentation of `TcpClient.Connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.connect?view=netframework-4.8) it says it will throw one of the following:

- `ArgumentNullException`
- `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`
- `SocketException`
- `ObjectDisposedException`
- `SecurityException`
- `NotSupportedException`

Why will it throw `System.AggregateException`?

Comment: If i do not wap it inside Task.Run() then how would i implement timeout for tcp connection? tcpclient.readtimeout or writetimeout not working.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => {
    tcpClient.Connect(host, port);
});
```

wraps your `.Connect()` call. And `Task.Run()` always throws `AggregateException` with the real exception inside it. In order to fix this either inspect the exception or even better use the asynchronous variant of `.Connect()`:

```
Task t = tcpClient.ConnectAsync(host, port);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

What i did finally is:

```
tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 5000;
 tcpClient.SendTimeout = 5000;
 tcpClient.Connect(host, port);
 catch (SocketException) {
                Console.WriteLine("Could not connect to: {0}", port);
                Console.WriteLine("Socket exception. Check host address and port.");
            }
```

It seems to be working.

Comment: Was this done inside the `Task.Run`? It would help if your code here was in context and the indentation was fixed.